# ElascticSearch subfield search appears to stop on first occurence

Tags: elasticsearch

In the following document I would like to query all 'name' fields that contain 'bill'.

```
PUT /my_index/blogpost/2
{
  "vendor":     {
    "name":     "bill" 
  },
  "user":     {
    "name":     "bob"
  }
}
```

The following query properly returns the document:

```
GET /my_index/blogpost/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": {
            "name": "bill"
            }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But searching for 'bob' instead does not return the document.

Where is my wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the full path to the field against which you are searching:

```
POST /my_index/blogpost/_search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "match": {
                  "user.name": "bob"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used for testing:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/74b124fd90aa3c7d422b3ef13933ce419b44714e

Comment: Yes, I know that searching each individual field works. Now let's suppose I really want to search in all the fields and I don't even have the root names for them.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Sorry, it's a common error. Have you tried using the `"_all"` field? You would have to specify which fields you *don't* want to be searched in your mapping somehow. Or you could collect the fields and list them in a `bool should`, or something, in your query. Also there are various ways you could reorganize your index mapping to allow for the sort of querying you need. But I don't think there is an out-of-the-box way to do  precisely what you're asking.